Auto scrolling to top with browser back button
In my NextJs app, when I use back button in browser, page scroll to top itself then route changing starts.
For example:
I on the home page, go to any page. There scroll down, ... let it be to footer. Click the back button in browser. Scrolling to top, route changing..
How disable this behavior? Can I disable any auto scrolling?

module.exports = {
  scrollRestoration: false
}

Add this configuration to your next.config.js file to disable the default scroll restoration behavior in NextJS.
This tells NextJS not to automatically scroll to the top when navigating between pages.
